# How to improve reliability of this AppleScript that launches a Safari tab?

Tags: applescript

I have a perfectly working script that breaks after I updated Safari to version 15, on Big Sur.

```
    tell application "Safari"
        set theWindow to first window
        tell theWindow to set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:theUrl})
        set miniaturized of theWindow to false
        set tabTotal to count of tabs of theWindow
    end tell
```

The problem happens on line 3. The tab is created with the correct URL,shows that it's loading briefly, then suddenly after about 1 sec, it stops loading and the URL goes blank, leaving me with a tab that is on a "Start Page". The issue is intermittent but it breaks more that it succeeds.

I tried a delay and failed. Also tried retry, but I feel it's becoming more complicated than it should, please advice, thank you.

P.S. Seems like the issue is Safari 15, opening links in new tab has become unreliable. Work around is to copy the link and paste it into the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
    tell application "Safari"
        set theWindow to first window
        tell theWindow to set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:theUrl})
        set miniaturized of theWindow to false
        set tabTotal to count of tabs of theWindow

        (* Safari 15 Fix to intermittent loading bug. *)
        script BugWaiter
            tell document of theWindow
                if its name is "Start Page" then return missing value

                if its name is not "Untitled" then return true
            
                if its source is not "" then return true 
            end tell
        end script

        -- runs the script until result is not missing value, up to 3x, delay 1 for each fail.
        set waitResult to waiter's exec on result for 3
        if waitResult is missing value then set URL of document of theWindow to theUrl
    end tell
```